# fetch a word in strings Android/Java

Tags: java, android

So I'm beginning with Android/Java programming. I want to try to find a word in a sentence. Say the user inputs in the EditText a sentence i.e. "My friend is a cowboy." The app should detect the word **cowboy** from a the String array. i.e.

```
 String[] words = {"cowboy", "animal", "monster"};
```

This is what I've tried:

```
 String[] words = {"cowboy", "animal", "monster"};
Boolean b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    view = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

    ok = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String string = text.getText().toString();
            b = string.indexOf("cowboy") > 0;
            view.setText(b.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

But it's giving me a false answer. What is wrong with my code? And in the indexOf method, I don't know how to put the string array for that. I hope someone will help me fix this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try the following:**

```
String[] words = {"cowboy", "animal", "monster"};
String s = "My friend is a Cowboy";
boolean check = false;

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (s.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
        check = true;
    } else {

    }
}
if (check) {
     System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
     System.out.println("No");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try iterating through your array and seeing if the base string contains all of the elements in the array. It would look something like this:

```
private boolean contains(final String string, final String[] strings){
    for(final String s : strings)
        if(!string.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase()))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your immediate response, I can't seem to figure out how to add your code to mine. Care to explain? Thanks.

Comment: Well, add that method in your code first and then instead of doing `string.indexOf....` just do `b = contains(string, words);` It returns true if the string contains all elements in array, else false.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Send from my phon so syntax errors included ;-)

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String string = text.getText().toString();
        boolean hit == false;
        // b = string.indexOf("cowboy") > 0;
        for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
            if (string.indexOf(words[i])!=-1){
                hit == true;
                break;
            }
        }
        view.setText(b.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: galaxy tab 10. I used chrome browser to write this.

Comment: Gotta try this one. Thanks.