# Get the meaning of a word/ String array

Tags: java, android

So this is the continuation of my question from this thread: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431908/find-a-word-in-a-sentence-android-java/18432244?noredirect=1#18432244)

```
    String[] words = {"cowboy", "animal", "monster"};
    String[] meanings = {"meaning1", "meaning2", "meaning3"};

    boolean check = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (s.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
        check = true;
    } else {

    }
    }
   if (check) {
   System.out.println("Yes");
   } else {
   System.out.println("No");
   }
```

But I can't seem to figure out how and where to put the specific meaning of each word that has been typed by the user in the edittext. Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See whether the following thread helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static String[] words = { "Cowboy", "animal", "monster" };
    static String s = "My animal is a Cowboy";
    static boolean check = false;
    static String[] meanings = {"meaning1", "meaning2", "meaning3"};
    static ArrayList<String> typed_words = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> typed_meanings = new ArrayList<String>();


        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (s.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {

                typed_words.add(words[i]);
                typed_meanings.add(meanings[i]);
                check = true;

            } else {

            }

        }

        if (check) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
            for(int i=0;i<typed_words.size();i++){
                System.out.println("Word: "+typed_words.get(i)+" Meaning: "+typed_meanings.get(i));
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

what about something like that?

```
int index;
...
if (s.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
    check = true;
    index = i;
} else {
....
if (check) {
   System.out.println(meanings[index]);
} else {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `words` and their `meanings` have the same relative positions in the two arrays then re-use the index `i` to print the corresponding meaning as well. But, the `i` would now have to be defined outside the loop so that it has a bigger scope now and is available inside the `if` check.

```
int i = 0
for (; i < words.length; i++) {
  if (s.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
    check = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (check) {
   System.out.println("Meaning found: " + meanings[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since words and meanings arrays have the relative indexing, you can-

```
boolean check = false;

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(words[i])) { // We don't need "toLowerCase"

        System.out.println("Word: " + words[i] + "\tMeaning: " + meanings[i]);
        check  = true;
        break; // Match found; so get out of the loop

    }
}

if(check){
    System.out.println("Found!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Found!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `java.util.HashMap`in which every word maps to a meaning?

```
String s = "";
HashMap<String,String> meaningMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
//just for the example
meaningMap.put("cowboy", "meaning1");
...
if (s.toLowerCase().contains(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
    ouput = meaningMap.get(s);
}
...
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to use HashMap to store your data.

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
hm.put("cowboy", "meaning1");
hm.put("animal", "meaning2");
```

And then use

```
String s = yourEdittext.getText();
String[] words = s.split("\s+");

for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
  words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^\w]", "");
}

for (int i=0; i < words.length(); i++) {
  if (hm.containsKey(words[i])) {
    System.out.println("Meaning found: " + hm.get(words[i]));
  }
}
```

This basically gets the sentece form the edittext, splits it into words then checks if each word is in the HashMap. This is good if your list of words is going to be quite big in comparison to the length of the sentence.

Comment: You've got invalid escape sequence

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest  that you  make a Hashmap<String ,ArrayList<String>>

as you have more than one meaning for oneword.

so now just passing the word you need to find the meaning for.

you can.also use treemap if you need to store them in a sorted fashion.

so here's how you can find the meaning for a word .

ArrayList<String> meaning =map.get("cowboy");

for(String string : meaning ) {
Log.v("meaning",string);
}